# side nav dropdown menu not opening with bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I need to implement a side nav menu with sub menu 
the problem that I am facing is that the sub menu or dropdown are not opening , or not collapsing if they were open by default .

```
<div class="nav-side-menu">
    <div class="brand">Brand Logo</div>
    <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x toggle-btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu-content"></i>

        <div class="menu-list">

            <ul id="menu-content" class="menu-content collapse out">


                <li  data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#products" class="collapsed active">
                  <a href="#"><i class=""></i> UI Elements <span class="arrow"></span></a>
                </li>
                <ul class="sub-menu" id="products">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">CSS3 Animation</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">General</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Buttons</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Tabs & Accordions</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Typography</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">FontAwesome</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Slider</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Panels</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Widgets</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Bootstrap Model</a></li>
                </ul>

            </ul>
     </div>
</div>
```

so I have one dropdown menu  for testing, if I click any one of them they will not open

Answer (score 0):

may be this help you...

```
<head>
<title>Bootstrap 3 Collapsible Sidebar</title>
<!-- Bootstrap CSS CDN -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Our Custom CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">
```

```
<!-- jQuery CDN -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap Js CDN -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">

<nav id="sidebar">
    <!-- Sidebar Header -->
    <div class="sidebar-header">
        <h3>Collapsible Sidebar</div>
    </div>

    <!-- Sidebar Links -->
    <ul class="list-unstyled components">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>

        <li><!-- Link with dropdown items -->
            <a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">Pages</a>
            <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu">
                <li><a href="#">Page</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page</a></li>
            </ul>

        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that my problem is not with the html tags

I should include jquery library before the bootstrap libraries.